# Ranking a negative correlation as equal to a positive correlation on a column-by-column basis for distance measures

Tags: r, clustering, distance, heatmap

I am very new to r, but have managed to muddle together a functional script to tackle data from a screen I am working on. I have a list of mutants of genes in a signaling network and values (OD550) for a phenotype in a number of conditions. Some of these genes are predicted to act cooperatively and so I would expect to see them both high in some conditions and both low in other conditions. Other genes are expected to behave antagonistically and so I would expect one to be high when the other is low and vice versa. These rules should not hold for all conditions however as it seems that the genes are active in overlapping, but not identical signaling networks which are working under different conditions. In other words: we might expect that A and B covary in all conditions while C varies oppositely in half of conditions as it is antagonistic to the actions of A and B, but in the other half of conditions it is antagonistic to C and D while C and D have no relationship to A and B.

The question I am trying to ask through my analysis is which groups of genes are active in the same functional node either cooperatively or antagonistically. I attempted to do this with the following heatmap which clusters by 1-r^2 so that a perfect correlation or anticorrelation would result in a distance of 0.

```
biofilm_matrix <- acast(biofilm.df_norm, Gene + Date ~ Carbon.Source,
value.var="OD.550", fun.aggregate=mean)
pdf(paste(outputDir, "heatmap.pdf", sep=""), width=30, height=30)
heatmap.2(biofilm_matrix, col=my_palette, scale = "row", margins=c(15,15), trace = "none",
distfun=function(x) as.dist(( 1 - cor(t(x)))^2))
dev.off()
```

My questions is: does this method average the r value across all conditions for each gene, thus integrating noise where a given group of genes act together in some conditions, but not others? If so is there a way to cluster based on the number of times a pair of genes covary rather than on an average correlation value across all conditions? Is there a better way to do this?